# How do I to include a file in php without using include or require?

Tags: php

How do I call a function which is in a different file without including or requiring that file?

Comment: as i have to include a basic function file always in every script where connection.php is being called...

Comment: Why  you don't want to use include? If the file has so many other things, refactor it so that the function is isolated in some file and include it.  Or look up web services that expose functions (I'm not sure why you want to do this,so explain more)

Comment: but the problem is to make file path of basicfunction.php as it is always changing with reference to open directory

Comment: Ok , copy paste your code and we'll see where you're going wrong.

Comment: `$path_determine = explode ("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$totSlash = 4;
$RelativePath = str_repeat("../", count($path_determine)-$totSlash+1);
`

Comment: This is all convoluted and I suspect there's an easy solution if we knew what you're really trying to accomplish.  What is the problem you're trying to fix?

Comment: try Autoload PHP Class files http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. If you don't include or require it, PHP has no idea what's there. You can use .htaccess or php.ini to automatically include a file, which is identical to including it with require or include.

For example in .htaccess

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/full/path/to/a/prepend-file.php"
```

In php.ini

```
  auto_prepend_file = "/full/path/to/a/prepend-file.php"
```

Comment: can u explane?? please describe how to edit php.ini of server machine??

Comment: Depends on the OS and how PHP was installed, and the web server. For example, on my Ubuntu 11 workstation, it's /etc/php5/php.ini after installing with aptitude. Find it, edit it.

Answer (score 3):

Read it into a string and eval it.

```
$code = file_get_contents("somefile.php");
eval($code);
```

Comment: +1 well, with some restrictions in PHP file, this will work fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste it. But mind the license.

Comment: You violate one of the first software engineering principles that way.  Reusuability.